# Springboot API returns null response

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, kotlin, web-services

This API works fine; I can see it hits the server and returns 200. But the response captured in the client code is null. I have checked the response via postman and I can see the status code. Not Sure why client is not able to decode the response

```
@Bean
        fun buildClient(
            objectMapper: ObjectMapper,
            @Value("\${cbase-uri}") url: String
        ): Client {
            return FeignApiBuilder.builder(Client::class.java, url) { it }
                .build()
        }
```

API interface

```
@Headers(
    "Accept: ${MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}",
    "Content-Type: ${MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}"
)
interface Client {
    @RequestLine("POST /v1/test")
    fun submit(
        request: body
    ): ResponseEntity<Unit>
}
```

Implementation

```
override fun test(request: body) {
        try {
            val response = client.submit(request)
            if (response.statusCodeValue == 200) {
                logger.info("Success")
                return
            } else {
                throw Exception("Internal Server Error")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw Exception("Exception occurred while calling submit api", e)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is due to return type of API interface method. You are returning "ResponseEntity", can you change the return type to the expected type and check if that fixes the issue

Comment: And not just any `ResponseEntity`, but specifically `ResponseEntity<Unit>` — wrapping the type that explicitly means ‘no useful value’. It's no wonder that frameworks (and people!) would assume you don't want anything in the response.